# How can I use window.scrollY properly

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I just wan't to use a fixed header when the user scrolls up. but with my solution its by default fixed to the top.

if i use fixed by default it blocks the white stick at the top. i tried z-index and other things. If i give more z-index to the stick it blocks the menu. so user won't be able to click menu links.

[image]

can I active window.scroll after the first 50px height maybe.

[image]

```js
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState("up");

let oldScrollY = 0;

  const controlDirection = () => {
    if (window.scrollY > oldScrollY) {
      setDirection("down");
    } else {
      setDirection("up");
    }
    oldScrollY = window.scrollY;
  };

 useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", controlDirection);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", controlDirection);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <header
      className={styles.navbar}
      id={
        direction === "up"
          ? `${styles.fixed_navbar}`
          : direction === "down"
          ? `${styles.transparent__nav}`
          : ""
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

When your page height goes above 50, you navbar will be active and also I optimzed your code. could you please try this, thanks.

```
const [direction, setDirection] = useState("up");
const controlDirection = () => {
  console.log("fUNC CALLED")
  if (window.scrollY > 50) {
    console.log("FIXED NAVBAR")
    setDirection("down");
  } else {
    console.log("TRANSPARENT NAVBAR")
    setDirection("up");
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", controlDirection);
}, []);

<header
  className={styles.ajxb_navbar}
  id={direction === "up" ? `${styles.fixed_navbar}` : `${styles.transparent__nav}`} />
```

Comment: we meet again :) thanks but transparent nav is on the top now and it shows fixed nav when I scroll down.  also it didn't start after the 50px height.

Comment: Hi Julia, I have updated the answer, in `controlDirection` func I added the `console` can you please check on `scroll`, whether or not something is being printed on the console.

Comment: ah thank you! your solution is correct. but transparent__nav should active when the user scrolls down. fixed__nav when the user scrolls up. when I remove the transparent__nav class from your solution it works. but only showing the fixed__navbar.

Comment: Is the problem solved now?

Comment: nope :l if you can see my first post. I'm using the "navbar" class as default. then transparent__nav on scroll down and fixed__navbar on scroll up. for now, it shows fixed__navbar on every scroll. and transparent__nav at the top.

Comment: so transparent and fixed classes still should work the same. but it should active after the 50px.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I updated the code, now here I explain this code that I What am I doing with this code, your `navbar` class will be by default, your class will be `transparent__nav` when you scroll down and your class will be `fixed_navbar` when you scroll up, please also check whether or not something is being printed on the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246038/discussion-between-julia-schafer-and-ahmad-faraz).

Answer (score 1):

You should be tracking the value for `oldScrollY`  in state.